# Is a Power Distribution Unit safe for home use?

Tags: power-supply

I got my hands on a Power Distribution Units (Dynamode 8WS-V-SP-1U 13A) and 
Examples ca be seen [here](http://it-supplier.co.uk/dynamode-pdu-8ws-v-uk-iec-8ac-outlet-s-black-power-distribution-unit-pdu-pdu-8ws-v-uk-iec) and [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dynamode-PDU-8WS-V-SP-1U-Vertical-Distribution-Protection/dp/B0080OV7N2).

I was hoping to use it at home like a power strip. However, it has a big warning message that states it is "exclusively for cabinet use".

Is it safe to use? Why would it be for cabinet use only?

Answer (score 1):

Because it hasn't enough mechanical strenght to lie arround in your home in any positon. When you screw this device on rack is exposed only from front side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate on the implications and potential risks of this? For example, is it going to decrease the lifetime of the PDU or is it turning into a fire hazard?